# php date/time intervals with subscription

Tags: php, date, time, intervals

I need some help wrapping my head around this.  I am trying to develop something that does monthly, weekly, quarterly, yearly subscriptions. I need to figure out when the next charge date is. But I'm getting confused getting through the logic. I can easily calculate when a year is from the original transaction (`<? echo date("Y-m-d",strtotime($charge_interval, strtotime($original_charge_time))); ?>`), where $charge_interval is '+3 months' or '+1 month', etc. But.. if 3 months have passed, I can't just use that equation, because it will show the "next" date as one month from the original. Any advice?

EDIT: more precision. My data is stored in a DB, and I need to ensure its getting the "next" month rather than a month from original date. Say transaction took place Nov 15th. Its now July 6th. I want "next transaction" to say July 15th, NOT Dec 15th (which is what the above code would accomplish), and to say "we have already have 7 charges before".

Comment: You need to be more specific about what you need. I understand that you have orders(?) which are being charged monthly/weekly/quarterly/yearly, right? So you need a snippet which calculates the dates for the next charging? Is your data stored in a database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[strtotime](https://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.strtotime.php) is little-know, but can show itself to be very useful for this kind of use.

EDIT: here may be a clue:

```
$charges = 0;
$now = time();
$next_charge_time = strtotime($original_charge_time);
while ($next_charge_time < $now)
{
    $charges++;
    $next_charge_time = strtotime($charge_interval, $next_charge_time);
}
$next_charge_time = date("m/d/Y", $next_charge_time);
echo "You have been charged $charges times since $original_charge_time.";
echo "<br/>";
echo "Next charge will be on $next_charge_time";
```

Comment: Won't something like **strtotime("+3 month", strtotime($original_charge_time))** do the trick? I don't understand what your issue is, try being more precise...

Comment: edited comment above to give an example. i was already using strtotime in the way you're describing. but it doesn't achieve what I wanted.

Comment: Still not clear at all about your motivations. But I think I got it from what you commented on Aleksey's post, I'm editing mine.

Comment: Did not work. I'm sorry I'm being unclear, take a look at edited example above. I need only 2 things: When the next time a customer should be charged (based on start date, current date AND interval) and how many times he has already been charged, if at all.

Comment: Tested it, it perfectly works. Except there wasn't the number of time the customer was charged (edited).

Comment: Creadiff - great! $charges includes the original charge here?

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't php have a dateadd function of some kind to add a number of months to a date?

Like this one?

http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-add.php

Answer (score 0):

Use [DateTime()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php) with https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.add.php

Comment: But.. How do I ensure its getting the "next" month rather than a month from original date? Say transaction took place Nov 15th. Its now June 5th. I want "next transaction" to say June 15th, NOT Dec 15th, and to say "we have already have 5 intervals before"...

Comment: You need to record original date, add x month of billing cycle to it and if it's greater or equals of the current date you need to bill the customer.

Answer (score 0):

Try mktime(0, 0, 0, strftime("%d", $origtime), date("m")+1, date("Y"));

that would mean midnight of course (first three parms are H, M, S, you could use strftime for those too if you want)

that would work for the next calendar month, you could just remove the "+1" for the same month if you work out the day falls later than the current day.